# PHP ssh2_exec returning stream, but remote command not being run

Tags: php, json, ssh, stream

I am trying to run a command on a remote server using the ssh2 module. Logs show that authentication was successful, and ssh2_exec returns a stream (the documented success behavior).

Server side, SSHing into the server as the same account manually (through putty) allows me to run the command successfully.

When running my code however, my logs show the command is never even being called.

Here is the code controlling the session:

```
function connect() {
    $hnd = \ssh2_connect(Config\PORTAL_SERVER);
    if (!$hnd) return false;

    if (!\ssh2_auth_password($hnd, Config\PORTAL_USER, Config\PORTAL_PASSWD))
        return false;

    return $hnd;
}

function run($api, $function, $args, $hnd) {
    $args = implode(' ', $args);
    $stream = \ssh2_exec($hnd, "api $api $function $args");
    \stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

    $response = \stream_get_contents($stream);
    fclose($stream);

    return \json_decode($response);
}
```

And the code calling it:

```
$hnd = Portal\connect();
$result = Portal\run(
    'users',
    'all',
    array(),
    $hnd
);
```

json_decode receives a blank string, since the stream never returns anything. I can only assume I am mishandling my stream somehow, but that would not explain my command not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

The path isn't getting set up properly for the user when the session starts... I switched to absolute paths and everything is perfect.